# addClass to change html text when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a Jquery drop down which adds and removes class when selected.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/7owwvecd/34/)

Inside the hidden menu is a nav bar with links. I am trying to create a function when you select one of the links the name of the link replaces the text on the menu button.

```
<div class="btn-container menu small-4 medium-2">
    <a class="inline-block btn no-text-trans">sector</a>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    <article class="pane inactive">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </article> <!-- PANE ENDS HERE -->
</div> <!-- BTN CONTAINER ENDS HERE  -->
```

For example if the button menu one is selected, the text 'menu 1' replaces the text 'sector'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `class` to all hidden menu `<a>` say `class="links"` and write an event to capture click as below:

```
$(".links").on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('article').siblings('.no-text-trans').text($(this).text());
});
```

Updated **html**

```
<article class="pane inactive">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="links" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</article> <!-- PANE ENDS HERE -->
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7owwvecd/35/)**

---

**UPDATE**

Add an extra data-* attribute to your `'no-text-trans'` anchor like one below:

```
<a class="inline-block btn no-text-trans" data-original="products">products</a>
```

to store its original text and then write a `document click event` to capture all other clicks and check whether the `target` was anchor or its `children` and if yes do the default action else replace the text, as below:

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
   //check if targeted element is link or its children
   if($(e.target).hasClass('links') || $(e.target).hasClass('no-text-trans'))
         return;
   //if not replace each anchor with its original text taking from its `data-original` attribute
   $('.no-text-trans').each(function(){
      $(this).text($(this).data('original')).siblings('article').addClass('inactive');
   });
});
```

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/7owwvecd/39/)**

Comment: There's a bug on this function, when you select one of the link for example menu 1 the text 'sector' disappears and doesn't come back

Comment: it doesn't disappear, it will be there instead the text will be changed.. Try changing values inside `links` to **Menu 1, Menu 2, Menu 3** etc.. you will find the difference. @NewBoy

Comment: @NewBoy when you want it to come back?

Comment: Good question.. when you click outside of the element i.e anywhere the screen it changes back

Comment: @Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target),
    $ct = $target.closest('.btn-container'),
    $pane = $ct.find('.pane.inactive');
  $pane.add($('.pane:not(.inactive)')).toggleClass('inactive');
  if ($target.closest('.pane a').length) {
    $ct.find('.btn').text($target.text())
  }
});
```

```css
.inactive {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-container menu small-4 medium-2">
  <a class="inline-block btn no-text-trans">sector</a>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  <article class="pane inactive">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </article> <!-- PANE ENDS HERE -->
</div> <!-- BTN CONTAINER ENDS HERE  -->


<div class="btn-container menu small-4 medium-2">
  <a class="inline-block btn no-text-trans">products</a>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  <article class="pane inactive">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><p>Menu 1</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><p>Menu 2</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><p>Menu 3</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><p>Menu 4</p></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </article> <!-- PANE ENDS HERE -->
</div> <!-- BTN CONTAINER ENDS HERE  -->
```

Comment: There's a bug on this function, when you select one of the link for example menu 1 the text 'sector' disappears and doesn't come back

Comment: @NewBoy when do you want it to come back